# AngularJS: How to send data with $http.post() to url that is different from project URL

Tags: angularjs

i am developing mobile application in cordova with angularJS & want to send the data(parameters) with post request to the url that is probably a different project url where my RESTful service pages are stored.

I have written the following code

```
 $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    $http.post(base_url+"get/memberLogin.php", {'username='+username, 'password='+password}
    ).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            if(data.status == true){
                alert('data received');
            }               
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // net not available.
        });
```

I tried above code in the firefox browser & then received 404 page not found error.
The url which it is searching is this:

```
http://localhost:90/datacollection_mobile/Project/module-based/controlr-1.0/localhost:90/MobileREST/php/processing/get/memberLogin.php
```

instead of this:

```
localhost:90/MobileREST/php/processing/get/memberLogin.php
```

URL is overlapping. How to resolve that problem.

Note: my base_url i have defined as

```
var base_url = 'localhost:90/MobileREST/php/processing/';
```

Answer (score 0):

Put  `http://`

```
var base_url = 'http://localhost:90/MobileREST/php/processing/';
```